# How to set Monospace fonts in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is it possible to change the font being used in EA?

For instance I would like to change the font being used in the result field of a test to monospace.

Can this be done in EA v.10?

Comment: You mean in the document generator? The text field for the test (like all other text /notes fields) has just one font.

Comment: Not in the document generator but the font being used in all the text fields - is it possible to change that?

Comment: No. Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change color properties or font to diagram element:
select it from diagram and click `F4`- a  dialog will be opened.

Comment: Testing is a separate dialog. It's not part of a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default font for Diagrams in Enterprise Architect by going to Tools -> Options -> Diagrams -> Appearance -> Configure Default Element Fonts

Hope this helps!